# Show that $e^g=cf$ for some $ c\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

need help proving that g satisfies $e^g=cf$   for some $ c\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$
where  g is the anti derivative of $ f'\over f$ f  holomorphic function. I tried expressing e in terms of power series but no luck.

Comment: On which subset of $\mathbf{C}$ are supposed to be defined $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: it is defined on the unit disk

Comment: @RobertGreen f is holomorphic on the unit disk and f has no zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Consider $(\dfrac{e^g}{f})'$